# perform a search of database with multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to perform a search of database when user enters a persons name into textbox. The texboxes are dynamic, so whenever the user enters a number into the "No. of firemen on scene" textbox as seen in the snap shot below, the same amount of textboxes appear in the fieldset below under("List of firemen on scene").

However, my problem is that whenever I'm trying to perform the search, the search is only performed on the first textbox and not on the others. Could anyone assist me as to highlighting and/or explaining what the problem(s) may be?

[image]

---

### occurrence.php

```
 <label>List of Firemen On Scene</label><br>
 <div class="NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes" name="firemen_list"></div>
```

### search.php

```
<?php
require('connectdb.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['search_term']))
{
   $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['search_term']));

   if(!empty($search_term))
   {
       $search = mysql_query("SELECT `fighterID`, `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName` FROM `firefighterinfo` WHERE `firstName` LIKE '%$search_term%'");
        $result_count = mysql_num_rows($search);

        $suffix = ($result_count != 1) ? 's' : '';
        echo '<p>Your search for ', $search_term, ' returned ', $result_count, ' result', $suffix, '</p>';

        while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search))
        {
            echo '<p>', $results_row['firstName'], ' ', $results_row['middleName'], ' ', $results_row['lastName'], '</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

### search.js

```
function firemanAddingTextBoxes() {
var NumOfText = $("#NumOfTextBoxes").val();
$('.NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').empty();
var txtBox = "";

for (i = 0; i < NumOfText; i++) {
    txtBox += '<input type="text" name="fireman[]" id="search" required/><br>';
}
$('.NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes').append(txtBox);



$('#search').keyup(function () {
    var search_term = $(this).val();

    $('#search_results').html('Searching database...');

    if (search_term !== '') {
        $.post('php/fireman_search.php', { search_term: search_term }, function (data) {
            $('#search_results').html(data);
        });
    } else {
        $('#search_results').html('Not Found');
    }

});
return false;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the other field is dynamic, you'll need to use event delegation on the search `input`s. Also, you're adding elements with duplicate ID's, which is bad. ID's have to be unique, just use classes for this:

```
for (i = 0; i < NumOfText; i++) {
    txtBox += '<input type="text" name="fireman[]" class="search" required/><br>';
}
```

Change:

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
```

To:

```
$(".NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes").on("keyup", ".search", function() {
```